# UIView animation getting paused when another UIViewController is presented

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` as the rootViewController for my app. When a download is initiated I show a badge on my last tab and have it pulse colors to show that a download is happening:

```
- (void)incrementBadgeValue {

    UITabBarItem *moreTabBarItem = [self.tabBar.items lastObject];
    moreTabBarItem.badgeValue = @"↓";

    self.originalColor = moreTabBarItem.badgeColor.copy;
    UIColor *toColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    NSTimeInterval duration = 1.5f;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{

                         moreTabBarItem.badgeColor = toColor;

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         if (finished) {
                             moreTabBarItem.badgeColor = self.originalColor;
                         }
                     }];

}
```

This works great, until another `UIViewController` is presented over the window, or the user leaves and returns to the app. In these cases the animation is paused/stopped.

How can I continue this animation in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got a same issue. To resolve it

- Create a subclass of `UITabBarController` (name `CustomTabBarController`)
- Override `viewWillAppear` method to stop animation when another UIViewController is presented over the window, or the user leaves and returns to the app
- Override `viewDidDisappear` method to check and continue animation if needed.
- If you can't put the animation code inside `CustomTabBarController`. Create a `delegate` and use it on your controller class

**CustomTabBarController**

```
@protocol CustomTabBarDelegate<NSObject>

- (void)tabBarWillAppear;
- (void)tabBarDidDisappear;

@end

@interface CustomTabBarController : UITabBarController

@property(nonatomic, weak) id<CustomTabBarDelegate> customDelegate;

@end

@implementation CustomTabBarController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];

  [self.customDelegate tabBarWillAppear];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

  [self.customDelegate tabBarDidDisappear];
}

@end
```

**YourViewController**

```
@interface YourViewController () <CustomTabBarDelegate>

@end

@implementation YourViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  [(CustomTabBarController*)self.tabBarController setCustomDelegate:self];
}

- (void)tabBarWillAppear {
  if (/*Still need animation*/) {
    [self incrementBadgeValue];
  }
}

- (void)tabBarDidDisappear {
  // Remove your animation
}

@end
```